# Base Code Issues (?) with ASP.NET Core OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, oauth

I'm using the ASP.NET Core Authentication.OAuth package (version 2.2.0) to develop middleware for a unique authentication flow in my web app. I am using .NET Core 3.1. I'm running into several issues where it seems that there are constructors/methods missing from the package's base code, creating missing method exceptions that I cannot resolve (for example, this exception, which I've gotten around but haven't truly resolved: "**MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuth CreatingTicketContext..ctor**" which I got when trying to instantiate an `OnCreatingTicketContext` object). I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the OAuth package, so I don't believe it's a problem with my specific installation. Although I've managed to work around some of these errors, I'm presently unable to instantiate new `OAuthTokenResponse` objects in my extended `OAuthHandler` class.

Calling `OAuthTokenResponse.Success(response)` produces a missing method exception ("**Method not found: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthTokenResponse Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthTokenResponse.Success(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)'**"). If I try to directly specify each of the object's fields (as below), I am met with another error: "**'OAuthTokenResponse' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments**".

```
var payload = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
var result = new OAuthTokenResponse()
            {
                Response = payload,
                AccessToken = payload.Value<string>("access_token"),
                TokenType = payload.Value<string>("token_type"),
                RefreshToken = payload.Value<string>("refresh_token"),
                ExpiresIn = payload.Value<string>("expires_in")
            };
```

Indeed, it seems from the class definition that there is no constructor defined taking any number of arguments, though I suspect that it exists and just isn't accessible, so maybe that's to be expected. Whatever the case may be, I don't know what to do and I can't tell whether it's something I'm doing wrong or it's a problem with the package itself. Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem sprouted from having multiple references to the same set of packages. I had not realized that ASP.NET Core versions after 2.2 were not referenced by inclusion of Nuget packages and that the .NET Core 3.1 framework supplied the most recent versions. I uninstalled/deleted references to the version 2.2 packages and the problem vanished.